# How to fix 'Cannot resolve symbol READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE error

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TextView noMusicTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        noMusicTextView = findViewById(R.id.no_songs_text);

    }
    boolean checkPermission()
    {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    boolean requestPermission()
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},123);
    }
}
```

I also mentioned in this AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but still I am getting error

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
Cannot resolve symbol 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
```

kindly help me as soon as possible

I try to READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my code but facing issue ,I wanted to get this error resolved as soon as possible.

Comment: What is the file it imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usage is wrong:

```java
int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

You should use like this:

```java
int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```